# Android Material DatePicker hiding days

Tags: android, datetime, datepicker, picker, days

In my project, I am using Android's DatePicker for selecting a date (inside a DialogFragment). For Android >= 5, instead of showing the three spinning wheels, you get a calendar-style date picker where you can select your date.

However, the material picker has some strange issue: If a month has 6 weeks, the days from the sixth week of that month are unselectable. This picture should illustrate the issue:

[image: missing days on DatePicker]

October 30th and October 31st are in the sixth week of October, hence they are cut off - and they do not appear on the page for November. This also happens for January 2017 (because that month goes over 6 weeks as well).

Can someone enlighten me why this happens and how to get around this?

EDIT:
I have tried setCalendarViewShown(false) already and it is deprecated (and not working anyway, at least on Android 6.0.1)

Comment: In case somebody asks: Yes, I have tried an alternative library (DateTimePicker by wdullaer), but it is unsuitable for small screens

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because DatePicker is not adjusting it's size in given width and height params. Well you can disable calendarView using setCalendarViewShown(false) to get three spinning wheels to get your work done.

Comment: this method is deprecated (Deprecated - Not supported by Material-style calendar mode)